# How to count the number of equalities that must hold to prove that (R, +, .) is a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

In Grimaldi's "Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics", I came across
[this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrVob.jpg), where the author counts 125 equalities to prove the associative and distributive laws for this ring of 5 elements. When I tried counting the same, I arrived at a count of 130.

We have

${5 \choose 3} = 10$ equalities for associativity of addition. We simply choose 3 symbols from the set. (Order doesn't matter as addition is commutative)

${5 \choose 3}\cdot 3! = 60$ equalities for associativity of multiplication. Since multiplication need not be commutative, we cannot neglect the order.

$2 \cdot 3 \cdot {5 \choose 3} = 60$ equalities for the distributivity of multiplication over addition. The reasoning for this is as follows. We first choose 3 symbols in ${5 \choose 3}$ ways. Since addition is commutative but multiplication is not, we need to multiply this count by 3. ($x\cdot(y + z),\space y \cdot (x + z), \space z \cdot (x + y)$ are all different cases). Additionally, since multiplication is not commutative, $x\cdot(y + z)$ and $(y + z) \cdot x$ need to be considered separately, hence the factor of 2.

Summing, we get 130. What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you skipping the cases of repeated elements?

Comment: It seems that the author means that 125 equalities have to be verified for associativity of the addition (equations $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$), 125 equalities have to be verified for associativity of the product (equations $(xy)z = x(yz)$) and 125 equalities for distributivity on the right (equations $(x + y)z = xz + yz$) and 125 equalities for distributivity on the left.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin That makes sense. That would mean some equalities are over counted but I don’t think that’s the point there. Thanks for the quick reply!